# Table of contents of a Book and Fancy psframebox

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fancyhdr

I want to do the table of contents of a book, but when I tried to use the command `\chapter{}` it doesn't work. I guess the problem is that I'm trying to put it in a `\psframebox`, however, I need it in that way. Or do you know a way I can include the chapter without the title appearing twice?

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno,draft]{amsbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{rawfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphics}
%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\newcommand{\lm}{\text{\rm lím\;}}
\newcommand{\sen}{\text{\;\rm sen\;}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\text{\;\rm tg\;}}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12.2cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{18cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{6mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.2cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\newpsobject{grilla}{psgrid}{subgriddiv=1,griddots=10}
\begin{document}
%\include{cap0}
\include{cap1}
\end{document}
```

In cap1.tex I put the following code

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}%

\fancyhead[CE]{\sc J}
\fancyhead[CO]{\sc Obra}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{1.5cm}

\chapter*{
\begin{flushright}
\psframebox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black]
{{\huge\bf  \white ESCRITOS }}
\end{flushright}}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}


\newpage
```

Comment: Put `\protect` before `\psframebox`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thanks! It worked perfectly.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Sorry to bother you again, but It worked partially because the chapter name appears in the table of contents appears with the black box. I tried to put `\protect` before `\psframebox`, and `\chapter{ESCRITOS}`, however in the table of contents appears the letters in different sizes :(.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the formatting commands in the `\chapter` arguments is a bad idea, because they will also come in the table of contents and in the page header if you want the chapter title there. It is better to use a package like `titlesec` to do the job, because it separates the formatting from the text.  Here is a solution based on `titlesec`. I also put some text in the chapter to make the picture nicer.

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno,draft]{amsbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{rawfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphics}
%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\newcommand{\lm}{\text{\rm lím\;}}
\newcommand{\sen}{\text{\;\rm sen\;}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\text{\;\rm tg\;}}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12.2cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{18cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{6mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.2cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\newpsobject{grilla}{psgrid}{subgriddiv=1,griddots=10}

\newcommand{\formatchapter}[1]{\raggedleft\psframebox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black]{\huge\bf \white #1\strut}}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {}
  {\formatchapter{\thechapter}}
  {0pt}
  {\formatchapter{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\include{cap0}
\include{cap1}
\end{document}
```

And `cap1.tex`

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}%

\fancyhead[CE]{\sc J}
\fancyhead[CO]{\sc Obra}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{1.5cm}

\chapter*{ESCRITOS}

\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

\newpage
```

In general I would advise to use the more modern `\colorbox` command instead of `\psfancybox` because it belongs to the standard LaTeX stuff. That can simply be done by replacing the `\formatchapter` command with

`\newcommand{\formatchapter}[1]{\raggedleft\colorbox{black}{\huge\bf\textcolor{white}{#1}\strut}}`

[image]
[image]